# Изменения на всех страницах сайта.

Tags: html, css

Допустим имеется сайт. В верхнем правом углу - новости. Страниц, допустим, 100. Новости отображаются на всех страницах. Как сделать, чтобы изменив новости, они менялись на всех страницах?

Comment: А как сейчас реализован сайт?

У вас статичные страницы? Т.е. каждая страница самодостаточная и зависит только от себя? Или как?

Comment: Сейчас сайт только делается. Да, статичные.

Comment: Без программирования на серверных языках, у вас ничего подобного не получится, учите хотя бы PHP и MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Миша](/users/1679/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0) Булгаков, прежде чем работать с пхп (язык, для разработки динамических сайтов, веб ресурсов) почитайте немножко о веб серверах, например Апач сервер, как они работают, как настроит пхп с веб серваком, как работают HTTP запросы(GET,POST - без этих даже не постарайтес инклудить страницы).

Потом уже все станет на свои места, можете использовать код [@knes](/users/2825/knes)-a.
Для начала можете установить [denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/),[xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html) и там потренироваться. Поначалу трудно будет конечно, но все это к лучшему. Будет вопросы задавайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
include "news.php";
```

а в файл news.php заносите свои новости.

Comment: Не разбираюсь в php. 
Где создать include "news.php";?
Как в этот файл заносить информацию?

Comment: <html>
    <body>
      <div class="newsblock"><?php include "news.html"; ?></div>
      <div class="main_area">
        ....
      </div>
    </body>

news.html - обычная страница с новостями. news.php тоже может не содержать ни строчки php.